# HTML - Mobile Layout - Scroll Position After Orientation Change

Tags: html, css

I've run into an issue whilst trying to test out a layout for a mobile application. I've got two elements sitting in a container which are up flush against one another. If I scroll to one of the pages (using just the standard scrolling, no scripts) and change the orientation all is well and the element re-sizes itself properly. But when I revert back to the previous orientation the scroll position appears to be lost and the scroll position in-between both elements.

It's very difficult for me to describe since I am not sure what's going on so I have provided the [code I am using](http://jsfiddle.net/jnzCH/1/)

You need to load this on a device to see what's happening. Load it up in landscape, scroll across until all of the green page is visible and then change to portrait. Then go back to landscape. You will see half a red page and half a green page.

Is this something to do with the way I am setting my viewport or a known issue with webkit browsers, since this happens on both IOS and android (also chrome)?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I have no answer, but have run into similar issues. From what I can tell, it has to do with the browser title bar/search not being accounted for by the device during orientation changes. I've found the issue with absolutely positioned divs...which get out of position when orientation is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's quite logic actually :

Let's say you are on iPhone. You screen is 320x480 in portrait, 480x320 in landscape.

In portrait, your global div is 200%, so 640px. The green part is at 320px.
In landscape, your global div is 960px wide. The green part is at 480px.

If you go to the green part in portrait, you scroll to 320px. When you change orientation, you still are at 320px, but the green part is now at 480px : stuck in the middle.

Possible solution : javascript, listening to onorientationchange event and setting the right offset.

Other (but bad) solution : fixed width viewport, per exemple :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=400px,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```